# merging several hdf5 files into one pytable

Tags: hdf5, pytables

I have several `hdf5` files, each of them with the same structure. I'd like to create one `pytable` out of them by somehow merging the `hdf5` files.

What I mean is that if an array in file1 has size x and array in file2 has size y, the resulting array in the `pytable` will be of size x+y, containing first all the entries from file1 and then all the entries from file2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How you want to do this depends slightly on the data type that you have.  Arrays and CArrays have a static size so you need to preallocate the data space. Thus you would do something like the following:

```
import tables as tb
file1 = tb.open_file('/path/to/file1', 'r')
file2 = tb.open_file('/path/to/file2', 'r')
file3 = tb.open_file('/path/to/file3', 'r')
x = file1.root.x
y = file2.root.y

z = file3.create_array('/', 'z', atom=x.atom, shape=(x.nrows + y.nrows,))
z[:x.nrows] = x[:]
z[x.nrows:] = y[:]
```

However, EArrays and Tables are extendable.  Thus you don't need to preallocate the size and can copy_node() and append() instead.

```
import tables as tb
file1 = tb.open_file('/path/to/file1', 'r')
file2 = tb.open_file('/path/to/file2', 'r')
file3 = tb.open_file('/path/to/file3', 'r')
x = file1.root.x
y = file2.root.y

z = file1.copy_node('/', name='x', newparent=file3.root, newname='z')
z.append(y)
```

Comment: This might be obvious but I am unclear about what the last two lines are doing. Is z supposed to be the combined output file? Are those two lines doing the same thing? Is it possible  clarify variable naming and definitions here?

Comment: The file being written to needs to be opened in append (or write) mode. So use `'a'` instead of `'r'` when opening `file3`.

Comment: in order for the example to work, I also had to change the final row to:
`z.append(y[:])`